# Jframe import not found

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have a weird problem. I worked with Jframes before but at my current project i have made a GUI and my program didn't find jFrame. He gives an error on

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

When i use

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

He doesn't give an error but he alse not find Jframe.
Here is a piece af code:

```
package ServiceProvider;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SP {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
...
```

I am using an older version of eclipse(Gallileo) where i installed windiwBuilder en the swing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at your swing package if it contains JFrame class or not. It might be be the condition your lib is broken.. please re-install it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, type Ctrl-Shift-T (or Cmd-Shift-T if you are on a Mac).  In the search box, type "jframe".  You should see the `JFrame` class appear in the list and it will tell you what package it is coming from at the bottom of the dialog.  If you see it in this list, then it must be something off about the characters in your source code.

My guess is you are using a non-ASCII character somewhere in your JFrame import statement.  Try opening the Eclipse Preferences, type encoding into the search box, and see what character encoding your Workspace is using.

Comment: Thx for your answer. With doing this i have seen the problem. I am making a program with an older version of JRE (because of hard and software i need to use). This version doesn't support jFrame. Didn't think of that. I split my program so i can use newer version of JRE for my GUI.